What be causing a "Network Failure" error when I try to add AWS Cognito authorization to my API Gateway?
Result of trying to save after adding Authorizer
I keep getting "Network Failure" whenever I try to make certain changes with API Gateway. I can create new APIs, add methods, connect Lambdas to them, and deploy but I cannot enable or make changes to CORS or add Cognito Authorization to any methods. Has anyone else encountered this?
I created a new API, lambdas, and a new user pool on my region (us-west-1) and also on (us-west-2) and tried to add Authorization to the API methods but kept getting Network Failure. Connection between lambdas and API methods works and so does the Cognito UI login but I just can't add authorization. I was able to on Tuesday, 4 days ago but since Wednesday I've just been getting Network Failure.

This issue might be related to a temporary outage or service disruption in AWS. Check the AWS Service Health Dashboard to see if there are any ongoing issues in your region.

@IlyaKhrustalev I get a red error box saying "Unable to fetch events.
Unable to retrieve data, please try your request again later" when I try to check. I'm just confused since I haven't seen anyone else talk about it online and I figured at least 1 other person in the region would have the same problem and post about it.

Sometimes it happens, actually yesterday i also got the same error while updating the resource in api gateway.
The simple hack to solve this is to delete that method and create again and it will work  @JacobSchwarzenberger .

@MuhammadFarhan I had already tried that but just now what worked for me was setting up the Auth in the method wizard as opposed to doing it after I already created the method. Thank you for inspiring me to try again, I'm feeling quite relieved.

I figured out it was just some super annoying bug that was preventing me from making any edits to Gateway API components. I.e. can't add headers to integration response so I had to delete it and add it in the wizard, can't add headers or auth to resources, etc...
Thank you! @Muhammad Farhan

Save your code for your api function locally.
Then download the Sam Template CLI here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/using-sam-cli.html
Then create your https api using the cli.
Add your cognito authorizer in the Sam template as seen here.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-api-cognitoauthorizer.html
Configuring implementations like your building can be complicated when manually configuring.
Use Sam Templates and the cli!
